# Entity Framework and Synchronizing a database solution?

Tags: entity-framework, synchronization, entity-framework-4

I currently have an n-tier application using entity framework 4.0 and we're looking at synching the contents of database between redundant servers. Does anyone have any experience on tips on how best to approach a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an architecture point of view, you need to consider if you want to do this at the application level or the database level.

At the application level you could write to both databases any time you made a change.

At the database level you could use the replication tools build into the database that you use.

You could also use a 3rd party tool. There is also a [sync framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/sync/bb887608%28en-us%29.aspx) available from Microsoft.